# Script which will wait for a entry in database till certain amount of time

Tags: sql, shell, unix

I have table say x_table (only one column - x_column)) which gets updated after some time with new values ( time is not fixed ).

I want to write a shell script which will keep on checking this table till a certain value arrives and then say i want to delete that value from DB.

```
Like :
when x_column is not equal 10 , wait 
when x_column equal to 10 , delete from x_table where x_column=10.
```

Additionally i want to handle timeout as well , say my script waited for 10 minutes and entry still did not arrived ( in that case exit from script).

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Code :

```
actual=10

db_value=`sqlplus -s $DB <<EOF
set heading off
set feedback off
SELECT x_column from x_table where x_column=$actual;
exit
EOF`;


while [ $db_value = "no rows selected" ]
do
    db_value=`sqlplus -s $DB <<EOF
    set heading off
    set feedback off
    SELECT x_column from x_table where x_column=$actual;
    exit
    EOF`;

   sleep 5;
   wait=0;
   wait=wait+5;

   if [[ $wait -eq 600 ]]; then
   exit 1;
   fi
done

sqlplus -S $DB << EOF
set echo off head off verify off feed off pages 0 
delete from x_table where x_column=$actual;
EOF


exit;
```

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: Next time move `wait=0` outside the loop. Your current example with    `wait=0; wait=wait+5;` tries to make wait equal to 5 (but you need to change it into `(( wait = wait + 5 ))`, since `wait=$wait+5` or `wait+=5` will make wait "05").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
interval=600
loop_count=12
counter=0
while true
do
    $counter=`expr $counter + 1 `
    db_value=`sqlplus -s $DB <<EOF
    set heading off
    set feedback off
    SELECT x_column from x_table where x_column=$actual;
    exit
    EOF`;

   if [ $db_value -eq 10 ]; then
      sqlplus -S $DB << EOF
      delete from x_table where x_column=$actual;
      EOF
      exit 0
   else
      if [ $counter -eq $loop_count ]
      then 
         echo "No rows deleted after checking for `expr $interval * $loop_count                     ` seconds , exiting script"
         exit 1
      else
         sleep $interval
      fi
   fi
done
```